# GTM javascript does not fill variables

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to use predefined variables for a simple GTM javascript macro, however, the variables do not load. Why is my code not loading the variables?

code:

```
function () { 
 var value = {{Click URL}}; 
 var begin = value.indexOf(":")+1;
 var end = value.substr(-1);
 return value.slice(begin,end); 
}
```

Comment: `value.substr(-1)` does not return the index but the value. use `return value.slice(begin)`

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark, but the click variables are not enabled by default. Check if they are enabled in variables/built in variables:

[image: GTM builtin variable configuration]

You'd need to set the checkbox in front of Click URL.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it by leaving out the "end" variable (slice automaticlly uses the last character if you do not feed it the second argument). It looks like this now:

```
function () { 
 var value = {{Click URL}}; 
 var begin = value.indexOf(":")+1;
 return value.slice(begin); 
}
```